# Period of equation

Tags: trigonometry

checking over a problem I did in the back of the book and it had slightly different answer. I am checking to see if I am correct or where I went wrong. I am to find the period and amplitude of the equation:

$z=3cos(u/4)+5$

which I came up with:

Amp: 3

Period: 8$\pi$/u

While the book states the period as just 8$\pi$

To find my answer I went:

$2\pi/(u/4)$ = 8$\pi$/u

Comment: Every time $u/4$ increases by $2\pi$, the function repeats. So every time the **variable** $u$ increases by $8\pi$, the function repeats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The period should not depend on the variable $u$. To find the period we wish to find $T$ such that:

$3\cos(\frac{u}{4})-5=3\cos(\frac{u+T}{4})-5=3\cos(\frac{u}{4}+\frac{T}{4})$.

The period of $\cos(u)$ is $2\pi$ so it must be that $\frac{T}{4}=2\pi$ hence $T=8\pi$.

Comment: I just fail to see the difference between $8\pi/u$ and $8\pi$

Comment: $\frac{8\pi}{u}$ suggests that the period of the equation depends on the variable $u$. This shouldn't be since the period of an equation is constant.

Comment: @Amzoti yes It states the amp = 3